# RxJS: wait for a Subscription to receive the next value

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm using `RxJS` in an Angular project and I have a `Subscription` to an `Observable` that emits values at a regular interval.

In the same component, I'm also using `RxJS` (combined with the Angular http client) to make a web call and subscribe to it.

What I want to do is simple: when I make my web call and it has returned a result, I want to wait until the `Subscription` receives the next value before processing the result. Let's see it better with a code sample:

Suppose I have this Subscription that receives new values from an Observable at regular intervals:

```
tenantStatusSub: Subscription;
```

Here's what I want to do, explained in the comment:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(...).subscribe({
  next: result => {
      /* I want to wait here for tenantStatusSub to receive a value before proceeding */
  },
  error: err => {
    //...
  }
});
```

I'm sure there is a straightforward way to do this, but I'm still learning RxJS so I'm not sure what the best/cleanest way is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can wait for the tenantStatusSub-subscription itself. Yet you can wait for the next emission of the observable that the tenantStatusSub-subscription refers to. I suggest you to use `switchMap()` to chain your http-request directly to the observable that receives the continuous flow of emissions. What's more you can use `first()`, to trigger "unsubscribe" after the first value has arrived:

```
tenantStatusObs$: Observable<any> = observableThatReceivesAFlowOfValues;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<any>('http://www.some-url.com').pipe(
        switchMap(resultFromApi => {
            return this.tenantStatusObs$.pipe(
                first(), // unsubscribes after the first value has been emitted
                tap(tenantStatus => {
                    console.log('Tenant Status:', tenantStatus);
                    console.log('Result from API:', resultFromApi);
                })
            )
        })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution does exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

CombineLatest can do this but it's not great. If tenantStatusSub emits regularly within the time interval it takes to get a response, this will work. Even so, the answer with switchMap below (though a bit more complex) should be much more robust.

```ts
combineLatest([
  tenantStatusSub,
  this.httpClient.get<any>(...)
]).pipe(
  skip(1),
  take(1)
).subscribe({
  next: result => {
    // both values in result here
  },
  error: err => {
    //...
  }
});
```

---

Update:

Once you have your http response, acquire the next tenant status and merge the two values into a single output. Since the switch into `tenantStatusObs$` is long-lived, you'll need to unsubscribe via `take(1)`.

```ts
this.httpClient.get<any>(...).pipe(
  switchMap(httpRes => this.tenantStatusObs$.pipe(
    map(tenantStatus => ({ httpRes, tenantStatus })
  )),
  take(1)
).subscribe({
  next: ({ httpRes, tenantStatus }) => {
    // both values available here
  },
  error: err => {
    //...
  }
});
```

An Aside:

In this case you could write `take(1)` after either the `map` or the `switchMap` operator. They'd create the same output. Semantically, however, they have different meanings.

- **After map means:** "At most one (paired) emission per tenantStatusSub emission"
- **After switchMap means:** "At most one (paired) emission"

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I want though, at least I think. I want to wait for the next result AFTER the http request has been done. This doesn't look like it guarantees that, it might get a value from tenantStatusSub before obtaining the http result, correct?

Comment: @Master_T, ah yeah, that's true. I've updated the original answer to work. I've also added another take with switchMap that should work.